# How to extract email-address-only from InboundMailHandler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Question about InboundMailHandler.

```
class MailHandle(InboundMailHandler):
  def receive(self, mail_message):

mail_message.sender may contained "John Bolton <john78@mail.com>". How can i extract "john78@mail.com" from it?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using this regex, which works very well. It might theoretically be possible to engineer a sender which fails this regex, that's why I catch the exception and alert about the address. It has not happened yet though.

```
try:
    sender = re.search('<?([^<>]+)>?$',mail.sender).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    ...
```

The other answer is not compatible with the official email address format, as defined per RFC 2822.

> Normally, a mailbox is comprised of two parts: (1) an optional display
> name that indicates the name of the recipient (which could be a person
> or a system) that could be displayed to the user of a mail
> application, and (2) an addr-spec address enclosed in angle brackets
> ("<" and ">"). **There is also an alternate simple form of a mailbox
> where the addr-spec address appears alone, without the recipient's
> name or the angle brackets.**

Please note that this snippet mentions recipients, but if you read the spec, it applies to senders also.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4

Answer (score 1):

without an regex e.g.:

```
s = "John Bolton <john78@mail.com>"
email = ''.join([e for e in s.split() if '@' in e])[1:-1]
```

Comment: While perhaps more elegant than a regex, it's not compatible with RFC 2822.

Comment: he didn't ask for rfc-compliance afaik. that's why i didn't even bother with re.